# Show success or fail alert in AJAX JSP after insert statement

Tags: ajax, jsp

I'd need some help displaying a status msg to the user, when an insert is successful or not.

my ajax is like this

```
<script>
function insertData(){
$.ajax({
url: "add.jsp",
type: "post",
dataType: "text",
data: {
userid:$('#userid').val(),
smeid:$('#smeid').val(),
weeks:$('#weeks').val(),
worktype:$('#worktype').val(),
comments1:$('#comments1').val(),
comments2:$('#comments2').val(),
comments3:$('#comments3').val(),
managerID:$('#managerID').val(),
success: function() {
    alert("success");
}
}
});
}
</script>
```

My jsp page where the insertion happens is like this

```
// variables

try
{

// establish connection
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
int x=st.executeUpdate( // query );
if (x<1)
{
    out.println("false");
}
else
{
    out.println("true");
}        
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.print(e);
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'd want to show alert when the insert has failed. How to return that from the jsp to ajax.

EDIT 1:

Tried the below addition for JSP:

```
String msg;
if (x > 0)
{
   msg ="true";//inserted
}
else
{
    msg = "false";//not inserted
}   
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
response.getWriter().write(msg);//this send back to ajax success function
}
catch(Exception e)
{
System.out.print(e);
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and below for ajax:

```
<script>
function insertData(){
$.ajax({
url: "add.jsp",
type: "post",
dataType: "text",

data: {
userid:$('#userid').val(),
smeid:$('#smeid').val(),
weeks:$('#weeks').val(),
worktype:$('#worktype').val(),
comments1:$('#comments1').val(),
comments2:$('#comments2').val(),
comments3:$('#comments3').val(),
managerID:$('#managerID').val(),
success: function(data) {
    var values = $.trim(data); //triming value if there is any whitespaces
    alert(values);
        if (values == "true") {
      alert("Done inserted"); //show alert
    } else {
      alert("Sorry not inserted");
    }
  }

}
});
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just send some `values` back to ajax `success` and check that value against some condition depending on this show your `alert`.

So , your **jsp** will look like below :

```
String msg="";
if (x > 0)
{
   msg ="true";//inserted
}
else
{
    msg = "false";//not inserted
}   
response.getWriter().write(msg);//this send back to ajax success function
```

And your **ajax success** function will look like below :

```
function insertData() {
   $.ajax({
     url: "add.jsp",
     type: "post",
     dataType: "text",
     data: {
          userid: $('#userid').val(),
          smeid: $('#smeid').val(),
          weeks: $('#weeks').val(),
          worktype: $('#worktype').val(),
          comments1: $('#comments1').val(),
          comments2: $('#comments2').val(),
          comments3: $('#comments3').val(),
          managerID: $('#managerID').val()
        }, //close here
     success: function(data) {
          var values = $.trim(data); //triming value if there is any whitespaces
          alert(values);
          if (values == "true") {
            alert("Done inserted"); //show alert
          } else {
            alert("Sorry not inserted");
          }
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Im not sure if the value sent back is correct. var values returns null. Not sure why. I checked ,the data is getting inserted into the db but the alert shows not inserted.

Comment: `alert(data)` inside your success function and see what does it gives.Did you change the `if-else` as i suggested in above code ?

Comment: yes, did exactly that. Thats how i understood it returns null, i see just a blank alert box

Comment: can you show your updated code? because this code should work..may be problem is somewhere else.Also can you add `response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");` before `response.getWriter().write(msg);` and check onces ?

Comment: your `data:{ }` is not close properly its closed after success function but , it should get close before success function. Also, i tested above code it worked.Check updated code .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214903/discussion-between-adam-smith-and-swati).